# I get an error message in the code that DesiredCapabilities for Chrome is obsolete

Tags: c#, selenium

In part of my code, I get an error that says the code is unreachable.

In the second part, I get an error message that DesiredCapabilitie is obsolete.

How can I solve this problem?

My code is as follows:

public void CreateWebDriver()
        {

```
        if (false)
        {
            var pathToDriver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToChromeDriverLocal"];

            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
            WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(pathToDriver, chromeOptions);
        }
        else if (true)
        {
            var pathToDriver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToChromeDriverRemote"];

            DesiredCapabilities chromeCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
            chromeCapabilities.SetCapability("chrome.binary", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
            WebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(pathToDriver), chromeCapabilities);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(false){
// code unreachable because condition is always false
}

// You have to try like this
int a=5,b=10
if(a>b){ // do something 
}
else if(a=b){ // do something 
} 
else { // do something 
}
```

Comment: So in othe words, would i rather just delete the unreachable code?

Comment: @DanA - you should put the code in correct condition. If code is not required then you can delete it.

Comment: Thank you Amit for the help. I'll try to review the code and remove if need be.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve the DesiredCapabilities part?